# Finding position of all needles in haystack

Tags: php, strpos

I'm trying to find the position of all needles in a haystack:

```
$haystack = 'one twoo two one postpone twool';
$needles = array('one', 'two', 'three');
foreach ($needles as $needle) { 
  if (stristr($haystack, $needle)) { // list position of all needles
    $pos[strpos($haystack, $needle)] = $needle;
  }
}
print_r($pos);
```

The value of `$pos` is here:

```
Array ( [0] => one [4] => two )
```

However, expected was:

```
Array ( [0] => one [9] => two [13] => one)
```

So two things go wrong:

- `twoo` is marked as being an occurence of `two`
- the loop apparently doesn't match the second occurence of `one`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an easy way, you could use `preg_match`:

```
foreach ($needles as $needle) {
    if( preg_match_all( '/\b' . $needle . '\b/', $haystack, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE ) ) {
        foreach( $matches[0] as $match )
            $pos[$match[1]] = $needle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Appears to be very elegant, but when I run it, $pos is empty?

Comment: Sorry, needed to use `preg_match_all` instead of the `g` regex flag, and it returns the results in a slightly different format, but my updated code should work.

Comment: @Pr0no Regex is right, a couple of other bits and pieces are wrong - should use `preg_match_all()` as PHP have no `/g` modifier (that's from Javascript) and the array format returned by that is stupid so you have to loop key `0` of `$matches`.

Comment: You may also want to `ksort($pos);` afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Based on Rawkode's suggestion:

```
function strpos_recursive($haystack, $needle, $offset = 0, &$results = array()) {                
    $offset = strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset);
    if($offset === false) {
        return $results;            
    } else {
        if(substr ($haystack, $offset + strlen ($needle), 1) == ' ' || ( $offset + strlen ($needle) ) == strlen ($haystack)) {  
            if(substr ($haystack, $offset - 1, 1) == ' ' || $offset == 0) {
                $results[$offset] = $needle;
            }
        }
        return strpos_recursive($haystack, $needle, ($offset + 1), $results);
    }
}

$haystack = 'one twoo two one postpone twool one three';
$needles = array('one', 'two', 'three');
$pos = array ();

foreach ($needles as $needle) { 
    if (stristr($haystack, $needle)) {
        $pos += strpos_recursive($haystack, $needle);
    }
}
ksort($pos);
print_r($pos);
```

I also added a check to make sure the next character is either a space or it's already the end of the haystack, so it won't match things like `twoo`.

Comment: This also matches `one` in `postpone`...so perhaps regex is the better option after all?

Comment: One second, I'll add a check for a preceding space as well.

Comment: Thanks for your time and attention. However, an odd thing. It doesn't catch the final needle in haystack: `one twoo two one postpone twool one => Array ( [0] => one [13] => one [9] => two )` but `one twoo two one postpone twool one three => Array ( [0] => one [13] => one [32] => one [9] => two )`? BTW - I added a ksort for easier reference.

Answer (score 1):

You should use regex. Try this:

```
$haystack = 'one twoo two one postpone twool';
$needles = array('one', 'two', 'three');

foreach($needles as $needle) 
{
    $regex = "/\b$needle\b/";

    if (preg_match_all($regex, $haystack, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE))
    {
        if (is_array($matches[0]))
        {
            foreach($matches[0] as $match)
            {
                $pos[$match[1]] = $match[0];
            }
        }

    }
}

print_r($pos);
```

Output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [13] => one
    [9] => two
)
```

Comment: This is great. Somewhat more elaborate than the accepted answer - thanks for your input though!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the offset of the last found position in-order to find future occurrences.

Somebody has already provided such a solution on the documentation comments
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#107678

Answer (score 0):

First point:
using stristr every substring is accepted as a solution, so I recommend using regular expression (see preg_match_all).

Second point:
the string is searched, for every element of the array, from the beginning of the haystack and only the first match is taken.
Again, use preg_match_all!